# android scrollview onclick outside content

Tags: android, onclick, scrollview, ontouchlistener

now scrollview is larger than content，when click area outside content，i want to do something,but can not get the onClickListener,anyone know how to modify?

layout xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scroll_content"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

java

```
    findViewById(R.id.scroll_view).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("chen", "scroll_view");
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.scroll_content).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("chen", "scroll_content");
        }
    });
```

[the layout view display like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYO99.png)

Answer (score 0):

the end,I replace "setOnClickListener" with "setOnTouchListener";

```
    findViewById(R.id.scroll_view).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
                Log.d("chen", "scroll_view");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```